# .aab not working with Autentication Bloc Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a mobile application that works correctly when I run it and I generate the .apk, but I have tried to upload it to the PlayStore and it has returned to me because it does not initialize well, it does not even enter the login, I have no idea what to check since when I run it it works correctly, for authentication I am using Authentication Bloc, this is my main.dart, the only thing I have noticed is that with the .aab it does not enter the condition and it goes to the else, so it does not enter the Login.

```
   void main() {
    runApp(
     MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
       BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
        create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc()..add(AppStartedEvent()),
       ),
     ],
    child: const MyApp(),
   ),
 );
}

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: "Administrador de pedidos",
  home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
    builder: (context, state) {
      if (state is UserAuthenticatedState) {
        return HomePage();
      } else if (state is UserUnAuthenticatedState) {
        return  LoginForm();
      } else {
        CheckInternet().checkConnection(context);
      }
      CheckInternet().checkConnection(context);
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Image.asset(
                "logo-login3.png",
                height: 200,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 64.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: const Color(0xFF00416A),
    fontFamily: 'Titillium Web',
    brightness: Brightness.light, colorScheme: 
    ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: const Color(0xFF94D500)),
  ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: Start the application in release mode on a physical device, it is easier to debug. Another thing you could do is add a [runZonedGuarded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html) and [sentry](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/) to catch errors generated in the widget tree in production.

Comment: When debugging it is done in debug mode with a physical device and if it works correctly the problem is when the .aab is generated it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I imagined that it was starting in debug, but an alternative is to start in release/profile mode to check what happens with your application and the difference between the apk and the bundle (.aab) is that the bundle contains 3 different builds for the store decide which one to use. [See here](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#release) how to start in release mode and [here how](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android) the app is build.

Comment: start in release mode not working, but not show error